# Twilio survey outbound calls

Tags: twilio, survey

I am very new to Twilio, in fact, I started yesterday. I have been following this survey infrastructure to implement the survey AVR, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/automated-survey-php-laravel. So far I have been successful in setting this up. However, I want to make it such that, instead of an inbound call, it is an outbound call. I want to call people to make the survey.

Q1, Is this possible? 
I can simply redirect the call to a number that will kick-start the survey, but that is a waste of resources if I have to do that every time.

Q2, The client I am developing this for will be surveying millions of customers/people, is there a way for me to drop all the numbers in a file and have the call file loop through each number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initiate an outbound call using the Twilio REST API.

Making Calls
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls

The URL used in your REST API call would point to your survey TwiML.

You can certainly loop through a list of numbers to update the To. You can use the statusCallback of the RET API call, to determine the call status for each call placed.